# I am trying to use JavaScript in (php > while loop) and give me action for each result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops

after getting data from sql I tried to click ok the button to add 1 number (sum sql data number + 1)
but the Java is still working on all the inputs for all the results that I an getting

```
<input  type="text"   id="<?php echo $row['number'];?>"  >

 <button value="1" id="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">1</button>     
<script>

var theTotal = 0;
$('#<?php echo $row["id"];?>').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('#<?php echo $row["number"];?>').val(theTotal);        
});

$('#<?php echo $row["number"];?>').val(theTotal);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code that this creates?  Is it what you expect it to create?

Comment: All your buttons are using the same `theTotal` variable. Is that what you want?

Comment: You shouldn't redeclare the same global variable during the loop. It should be declared once before the loop.

Comment: for example, on my data base i have 2 records, and when i use php to select data from sql the data will show in text-box, then i want to click on the button to increase the number by one, what is happening if i click the button all text box for the 2 results will add 2

Comment: Why do you need the variable `theTotal`? Just use `$('#<?php echo $row["number"];?>').val(Number($(this).val())+1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `theTotal` variable, just get the value from the input field, add 1 to it, and put that back.

```
$('#<?php echo $row["id"];?>').click(function(){
    var val = Number($('#<?php echo $row["number"];?>'));
    $('#<?php echo $row["number"];?>').val(val + 1);        
});
```

Comment: I already knew out that this is part of a loop processing the results of a database query. The `$row` variable makes this obvious.